# Efficiently synchronize streaming input with large SQL database

Tags: database, synchronization

I've got an efficiency problem on my hands and I'm looking for ways to solve it. Here is the situation:

- I have streaming row-based data coming into a system from an online source, each with unique `id`.
- I have an SQL database with existing row-based data, indexed by `id`.
- I need to update the SQL database with new data streaming in if it differs from the existing data already in the database.

The obvious solution is:

1. Read incoming row
2. Read corresponding row in database
3. If data differs, update the database

The large number of round-trips is making this algorithm infeasibly slow.

The alternative solution I have is to read the entire SQL database into memory, and compare with new incoming data. This eliminates the round-trips but the memory required makes this also infeasible.

So, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: Batching would seem to be one solution.  Either batch on a convenient time unit (say 10 seconds) or batch on a convenient number of records (say 100).  Then the comparisons can be made in the database and all will be faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It turns out I have a lucky optimization. Because I am simply updating the database with new data, I can issue a REPLACE instead of INSERT and let the database handle the overwrite. No need for round trips and very fast.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the database into multiple parts. (To address the size issue)
2. Design an algorithm to cache some of these database pieces into memory. (Speed)
3. Based on the incoming id, hash the query to the relevant database.

If step 2 is not possible to be achieved efficiently, this wont work.